# Finding the area enclosed within perimeter coordinates

Tags: geometry, area

Suppose we have a 2D grid of `1 \times 1` unit squares. Suppose we have some 2D shape (not necessarily convex, and the shape is not necessarily a solid volume) on this grid. We are given all the perimeter coordinates. Is there a way to determine the area enclosed within the perimeter?

e.g., suppose we have the shape 8 on a 2D grid. The perimeter of the shape 8 can be represented by the following list of coordinates
$$
[0, 0] \\
[1, 0] \\
[2, 0] \\
[0, 1] \\
[2, 1] \\
[0, 2] \\
[1, 2] \\
[2, 2] \\
[0, 3] \\
[2, 3] \\
[0, 4] \\
[1, 4] \\
[2, 4] \\
$$

The area enclosed by the perimeter is 15.

Comment: Perhaps, the Shoelace formula can help you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Comment: I’d also recommend looking into Pick’s theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem